# Express routing does not work with simple test case

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I think I am missing some concept with basic routing for Express.  See [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html)

I created some simple test code as follows in my server `index.js` file.

```
app.get('/foo', function (req, res) {
  console.log('foo path found');
  res.send('foo achieved')
})
```

In my browser(chrome) URL I type

```
localhost:3000/foo
```

to trigger the route but I get no response on the server or client.

I verified `localhost:3000` is up and running.

Port is set in a different file as follows:

```
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));
```

But also I get confirmation in the terminal as follows:

```
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('DEBUG: express: server up');
});
```

I am on a campus network that blocks some traffic, but b.c. this is localhost I don't think it should matter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're supplying enough information to correctly debug your issue.

I'd initially ensure that Express *is* listening on port 3000, double-check this line:

```js
app.listen(3000);
```

Ideally, this line should be at the bottom of the script.

Response to edit: Yes, this should not matter. `localhost` is an alias for the system itself. It's a loopback, similar to that of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I can type in `localhost:3000` into the browser and my web app will appear.  This is how I verified it.

Comment: I also get confirmation in the terminal and added that code to the Q.

Comment: Change `app.get('port')` to `3000` as an integer and rerun. `app.get` is not for this purpose.

Comment: It does look odd.  However it is part of the API to use getters and setters ... https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set

Comment: I updated the Q to include the setting of the port.

Comment: Notice the function signature is different from other use of `app.get( )`, in that there is not callback for simply setting and getting.  They should have called it getter or similar to avoid confusion.

Comment: I wonder what port routes use, can I assume it it she same port as the server?  I'm going to do a self ping.

Comment: self ping works and trace route verifies that it is not doing something odd.  However I can not set the port with ping / trace route.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have created two express app, as you have mentioned that you are using two different files, the localhost which you are able to run is the one which has `app.listen()` code, but this doesn't have the app.get()

I suggest you use a single file for now and try doing it.

Try out the following code, and check now with `localhost:3000/foo`.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/foo', function (req, res) {
  console.log('foo path found');
  res.send('foo achieved')
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

Comment: good idea.  I have a complex app that I have broken down into smaller parts to troubleshoot.  I will create a new single file "app" for testing here in a bit and let you know the results.

Comment: Yeah, sure. If you want to break it down, then you have to use the same instance of app in other files, you can do this by exporting it to another file.
Don't do app = express() multiple times.

Comment: After more testing, for some reason my middleware is breaking my routes.  Bizarre behavior.  I commented out lines of code until the route started working.  Completely trial and error makes no sense.